# getch on a Python Curses window doesn't return KEY_RESIZE if it's on a different thread

Tags: python, multithreading, ncurses, python-multithreading, python-curses

```
import curses, threading, sys

def thread():
    a = curses.initscr()
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()
    a.keypad(True)
    while True:
        char = a.getch()
        if char == curses.KEY_RESIZE: 
            print("key_resize", file=sys.stderr)
        else:
            print("other", file=sys.stderr)

threading.Thread(target=thread).start()
```

When I run this function on it's own, everything works perfectly fine - KEY_RESIZE is sent and everything is good. The problem arises when I call getch() from inside of a thread - key events seem to work fine (I haven't tested exhaustively or extensively) but KEY_RESIZE is never sent through.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there any way to fix this so that KEY_RESIZE is sent through regardless of threading?

I've tried it with the screen being initialized both inside and out of the thread, and on two different terminal emulators (gnome-terminal and konsole) on Python 3.4.3.

Print sent to stderr (which is redirected to another terminal) because curses tends to mangle the screen output. I'm also not handling fixing the terminal in this code, so you'll need to reset it to get it back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, curses is not thread-safe.  You can make curses applications work if you do all of the work in one thread.  Otherwise, you get unexpected behavior...

There is a compile-time configuration for ncurses which provides rudimentary support (i.e., a better starting point), but you are unlikely to encounter that in a prepackaged form, though it was introduced several years ago (see FAQ [Official releases](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#other_versions)).

Further reading:

- [ncurses - CRT screen handling and optimization package](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html)
- [use_screen, use_window - curses thread support](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_threads.3x.html)
- [new_prescr - curses screen-pointer extension](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_sp_funcs.3x.html)

During initialization, ncurses adds signal handlers for `SIGWINCH` and some others.  Using `strace`, I can see that python is capturing the `SIGWINCH` and ignoring it:

```
2722  <... futex resumed> )             = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
2722  --- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
2722  rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})           = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
2722  futex(0x7f94d4000c10, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
2722  --- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
2722  rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})           = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
2722  futex(0x7f94d4000c10, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
2722  --- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
2722  rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})           = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
2722  write(2, "Exception ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py'>\n", 82) = 82
2722  write(2, "Traceback (most recent call last):\n", 35) = 35
2722  write(2, "  File \"/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py\", line 1285, in _shutdown\n", 66) = 66
2722  open("/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
```

Because *python* has established a signal handler, *ncurses* cannot see the `SIGWINCH` any longer, and will not deliver `KEY_RESIZE`.  Presumably this is done in python to alleviate problems with signals in a threaded configuration.

Perhaps relevant information:

- [PEP 0475 -- Retry system calls failing with EINTR](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0475/)
- [Issue 25482: signal.set_wakeup_fd() doesn't work if the signal don't have handler](https://bugs.python.org/issue25482)

Comment: This is fair enough - but even in the case where there's only one curses thread, as in my code above, it doesn't work as anticipated.

Comment: And no use of standard input/output on other threads?  (It's hard to say...)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this? In the example, no, there's no use of stdin/out on other threads - the example code is everything that needs to be run to show what I mean.

Comment: I would try testing it, but the example appears to be only a fragment of a larger program.  For best advice, trimming the code down to a complete (but small...) example that shows the problem is the way to go.

Comment: The example is a small and complete example of the problem - key_resize isn't sent (or received?) when getch is on a secondary thread. I formatted my question poorly, and I've changed it to properly reflect it.