# Curses double input when returning with threaded input

Tags: python, curses

Im trying to use Curses to output/log mystuff out and also be able to send commands for example stop

I tried to add threading so the I/O can be non blocking but this resulted in the input duplicating !?
https://paste.pythondiscord.com/eyuwocatis

The while true loop is there cause i was testing outputs and will still use it[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getch on a Python Curses window doesn't return KEY\_RESIZE if it's on a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906183/getch-on-a-python-curses-window-doesnt-return-key-resize-if-its-on-a-different)

Comment: Duplicate output is more/less expected, because curses isn't thread-safe.  Aside from the usual recommendation to use just one thread for the curses work, you won't get much response on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your `Console` object in your new thread, and use some `setup` or `start` function inside your `Console` class to start the input processing. The following should work for example:

```
def runConsole():
    console = Console()
    curses.wrapper(console.start)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainThread = threading.Thread(target=runConsole, daemon=True)
    mainThread.start()
    
    while True:
        pass
```

then you would need some `start` function in your `Console` class to do the setup and call `self.run()` eventually:

```
class Console:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def start(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.h,self.w = screen.getmaxyx()
        self.window = curses.newwin(self.h-2,self.w,0,0)
        self.window.scrollok(True)
        self.InputContainer = curses.newwin(1,self.w,self.h-1,0)
        self.inputWindow = curses.newwin(1,self.w-2,self.h-1,2)
        self.inputField = curses.textpad.Textbox(self.inputWindow,insert_mode=True)
        self.InputContainer.addstr('> ')
        self.window.addstr(0,0,"Console Application started\n")
        today = date.today()
        today = today.strftime("%m-%d-%y")
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H-%M-%S")
        self.file = f"logs/{today}-{current_time}.txt"
        with open(self.file,"a") as f:
            f.write(f"[{current_time}] Console Application started\n")
            f.close()
        screen.refresh()
        self.InputContainer.refresh()
        self.window.refresh()

        self.run()
```

Comment: legend i appreciate you man :)